# Como posso pegar o value de uma tag span com jsoup?

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // write your code here
        Document doc = (Document) Jsoup.connect("https://cod.tracker.gg/warzone/profile/atvi/dezk%236971848/overview").get();
        System.out.println(doc.getElementsByClass("value").get(0));
    }
}
```

Me traz o resultado:

```
<span class="value" data-v-5edf1b22>67</span>
```

Só que eu quero pegar apenas o valor 67.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta executar o método `text()`:

```
System.out.println(doc.getElementsByClass("value").get(0).text());
```

Comment: Valeu amigo!...